# Забрать из ветки GIT только изменения одного файла

Tags: android-studio, git

Есть несколько веток: А, Б, С, мастер (каждая ветка наследуется от мастера).

Можно ли в ветке Б забрать изменения только лишь одного файла(пакета, папки и т.д.) из ветки А(без копи паста)? чтобы когда обе эти ветки мержатся с мастером не возникала вообще никаких конфликтов.. Как?

p.s. Работаю в Android Studio и гитом пользуюсь через IDE.

Comment: Вроде бы вам нужен `cherry-pick`

Comment: Можно, но не нужно как вы описываете. Это очень плохая практика. Вам нужно научиться разрешать конфликты и также уметь создавать т.н. *неизменяемые* ветки (immutable branches).

Comment: Конфликты разрешать можно, но бывает так, что ты сделал фичу, но еще не залил в мастер(не прошел ревью, не протестирован и т.д.), а в фиче есть кусок кода который  нужен другим участникам проекта(переиспользуемый код) и получается нужно всем сказать "ну копируйте вот там код, потом решим конфликты, если они появятся".. Про immutable branches нужно почитать, что это значит... спс

Comment: Значит ставьте приоритеты в процессе правильно. У вас проблема не в Git, а в процессах. То, что вы описали, ещё хуже.

Comment: Ну к гиту у меня претензий нет:)  Бывает такое, что в ходе разработки добавляешь какой то утилитный метод или экстеншен к какому то классу, и другие хотели бы заюзать эти методы, не дожидаясь полного завершения разработки в моей ветке, через копи паст как то дико, через "забрать некоторые изменения" получается совсем плохо) Как жить?:)) Именно в этом примере непонятны проблемы процесса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через ИДЕ выбрать в нужно коммите файл, правой кнопкой и Apply selected changes.

В коммандной строке

```
git checkout branch_name -- file_path
```

Comment: См. мой комментарий ТС. *Можно, но не нужно как вы описываете. Это очень плохая практика. Вам нужно научиться разрешать конфликты и также уметь создавать т.н. "неизменяемые ветки" (immutable branches).*